# where in condition not working in in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my function where I have written the select query

```
function userList($name,$logged_id,$friendlist)
{

    $this->db->select("concat((mu.first_name),(' '),(mu.last_name)) AS full_name,mu.user_id,user_type",FALSE);
    $this->db->from("mst_users as mu");        
    $this->db->where("user_status", "1");
    $this->db->where_in("user_id",$friendlist);
    $this->db->where('user_id !=', $logged_id,false);

    $this->db->where("email_verified", "1");        
    $this->db->where("mu.first_name LIKE '%$name%'");        
    $this->db->or_where("mu.last_name LIKE '%$name%'");            
    //$this->db->limit("3");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();  
}
```

This is my function call from the controller

```
function userList(){
    $arr_friend=array(127, 139, 138);
    $user_list = $this->search_model->userList(a,137,$arr_friend);   
}
```

This is the out put of the query.This out is wrong.

```
full_name   user_id     user_type   
Grace          1          2
admina         126        3
hancy          127        1
vaibhavaaa     132        1
arjun          137        1
ashish         138        3
sofia          139        1
emma           140        3
vaibhav        147        3
ashish         148        1
```

I want the record only for 127, 139, 138 these Id

```
full_name   user_id     user_type   

hancy          127        1 
ashish         138        3
sofia          139        1
```

out put should be like this

Comment: Better if you can pass `where` conditions in `string` format.

Comment: what is it  
`$user_list = $this->search_model->userList(a,137,$arr_friend);`
 there are 137 and a, can you explanation a,137 in your controller ?

Comment: 137 is logged in user

Comment: $arr_friend is array which contains the friends of 137.I want all the friends which having 'a' in their first name or last name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this because you use where_or in wrong way, replace this:

```
$this->db->where("mu.first_name LIKE '%$name%'");        
$this->db->or_where("mu.last_name LIKE '%$name%'");
```

with:

```
$this->db->where("(mu.first_name LIKE '%$name%'", FALSE);        
$this->db->or_where("mu.last_name LIKE '%$name%')", NULL, FALSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid problems you should use this:

```
$this->db->like('mu.first_name', $name);
$this->db->or_like('mu.last_name', $name);
```

you can also control where the wildcard (%) is placed

```
$this->db->like('mu.first_name', $name, 'before');    
// Produces: WHERE `mu.first_name` LIKE '%value' ESCAPE '!'

$this->db->like('mu.first_name', $name, 'after');     
// Produces: WHERE `mu.first_name` LIKE 'value%' ESCAPE '!'

 $this->db->like('mu.first_name', $name, 'both');     
 // Produces: WHERE `mu.first_name` LIKE '%value%' ESCAPE '!'
```

take a look to the documentation [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-similar-data)

Answer (score 0):

I changed this lines

```
 $this->db->where("mu.first_name LIKE '%$name%'");        
 $this->db->or_where("mu.last_name LIKE '%$name%'");
```

to this

```
$this->db->where("(mu.first_name LIKE '%$name%'");        
$this->db->or_where("mu.last_name LIKE '%$name%')");
```